# Extending an ActiveRecord Polymorphic Association with JOIN statements?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

My tables are set up such that `Child` has a `1:1` relationship with `Parent`.

They share a primary key (`id`):

- `Parent` has `id` and `type` and `name`
- `Child` has `id` and `health`

The `Child` is a polymorphic inheritance of the `Parent`. My goal is that `Child.find(1)` should return a `Child` object which responds to both `name` and `health`. The SQL statement would hypothetically look something like this:

`SELECT parents.id, parents.name, childs.health FROM parents 
LEFT JOIN childs ON childs.id = Parents.id 
WHERE parents.id = 1 AND parents.type = 'Child' LIMIT 1`

Thus I've attempted to use Polymorphic Inheritance in ActiveRecord:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
class Child < Parent
```

When I attempt to execute `Child.find(1)`, I see:

`` SELECT `parents`.* FROM `parents` WHERE `parents`.`type` IN ('Child') AND `parents`.`ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Child id: 1, type: "Child", name: "Hello"> ``

Notably, there's no `JOIN` on the `child` table, yet I receive a `Child` object back. This leads to the unexpected behavior that the `Child` object does not respond to `health`. Curiously, if I add an explicit table association to the `Child` class (`self.table_name = "childs"`), then the query pattern changes to:

`` > c = Child.find(1)
  Obtainable Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `childs`.* FROM `childs` WHERE `childs`.`ID` = 2 LIMIT 1 ``

Now I can access the `health`, but not the `type` or `name`.

How can I correctly create this JOIN association such that an attempt to load a `Child` object successfully JOINs the data from the parent?

---

Edit: these tables were created outside of an ActiveRecord migration (they are also accessed by other, pre-existing, non-Ruby applications) so I have no ability to change their schema. I can think of some fancy metaprogramming approaches, like responding to `method_missing`, that might let me lazy-load the missing attributes through a join... but I'm afraid I'll end up having to re-implement a bunch of ActiveRecord, like `delete`, `create`, etc. (which will lead to bugs). So I'm looking for some native/clean(ish) way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a typical Rails polymorphic association as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

So, in this case, when tables were created earlier by some other app, I suggest that you do something like this:

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "childs"
  belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: :id, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :name, :type, to: :parent
  delegate :name=, to: :parent, allow_nil: true

  after_initialize do
    self.build_parent(type: "Child") if parent.nil?
  end
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = 'foo' # otherwise, type column will be used for STI
  has_one :child, foreign_key: :id
  delegate :health, to: :child
end
```

and now you can access the health, type and name:

```
> c = Child.joins(:parent).find(1)
  Child Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "childs".* FROM "childs" INNER JOIN "parents" ON "parents"."id" = "childs"."id" WHERE "childs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Child id: 1, health: "Good", created_at: "2016-10-27 21:42:55", updated_at: "2016-10-27 21:44:08">
irb(main):002:0> c.health
=> "Good"
irb(main):003:0> c.type
  Parent Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "Child"
irb(main):004:0> c.name
=> "Hello"
```

and similar is for the parent:

```
p = Parent.joins(:child).find(1)
  Parent Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" INNER JOIN "childs" ON "childs"."id" = "parents"."id" WHERE "parents"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Parent id: 1, type: nil, name: "Hello", created_at: "2016-10-27 21:40:35", updated_at: "2016-10-27 21:40:35">
irb(main):003:0> p.name
=> "Hello"
irb(main):004:0> p.health
  Child Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "childs".* FROM "childs" WHERE "childs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "Good"
```

If you prefer, you can specify LEFT JOIN like this:

```
irb(main):003:0> p = Parent.joins("LEFT JOIN childs ON (childs.id = parents.id)").select("parents.id, parents.name, childs.health").find(1)
  Parent Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  parents.id, parents.name, childs.health FROM "parents" LEFT JOIN childs ON (childs.id = parents.id) WHERE "parents"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Parent id: 1, name: "Hello">
irb(main):004:0> p.name
=> "Hello"
irb(main):005:0> p.health
  Child Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "childs".* FROM "childs" WHERE "childs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "Good"
```

Comment: Excellent! Great solution to a nonstandard problem. Quick follow up though: `Child.new.save` will currently not create a `Parent` object, and likewise `delete` will not clean up the joined tables. I'm planning to just use `before_*` filters to implement the bookkeeping myself, but I'm curious if you have a better idea.

Comment: I have edited `Child` class so it automatically creates and deletes parent record., e.g. `c=Child.new` and then `c.name = "Foo"` `c.save` and to delete `c.destroy`

Comment: Note: this is definitely not a typical "Rails way", but it could work for this non-standard problem.